# XLS file 2007-2013

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I have the following VB code which creates an xls file:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim currCompleteFileName As String
    currCompleteFileName = "DynamicExcelFile.xls"
    Dts.Variables("DestExcelFileName").Value = currCompleteFileName

    If Not Directory.Exists(CStr(Dts.Variables("User::DestExcelFilePath").Value)) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(CStr(Dts.Variables("User::DestExcelFilePath").Value))

        File.Create(CStr(Dts.Variables(
                          "User::DestExcelFilePath").Value) + currCompleteFileName)
    Else
        File.Delete(CStr(Dts.Variables(
                          "User::DestExcelFilePath").Value) + currCompleteFileName)
    End If
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

My problem is that this code creates an xls 2000-2003 file but I need a 2007 -2013 file.

Could you please help me

Comment: This code creates an empty file named `DynamicExcelFile.xls`. The contents of that empty file could be binary data, text, whatever really. If you want the 2007 Excel File Extension, then make your file name `DynamicExcelFile.xlsx`. If you actually want the content to be the 2007+ format, then you need to show how you're filling that empty file. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks billinkc you're master!

Comment: Flagged to close because of a simple extension change fixes it

Comment: Formatting to avoid side scrolling and minor language change